# User input numbers not adding together

Tags: java, string, int

I'm trying to write a program that reads an integer from the user (through the keyboard), adds 100 to it and displays the result. All I can do is get them to concatenate like 2 strings, instead of adding the numbers together. I can't understand why it won't add them.

```
import java.io.*;  
public class Program  { 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

      System.out.print("Enter some text: "); 
      String text = br.readLine();  
      int number = Integer.parseInt(text);

      System.out.println(" Your value + 100 is " + ( 100 + text));
     }
  }
```

is the code I am using and:

```
Enter some text: 66
 Your value + 100 is 10066
```

is what is printed on the screen.

Comment: That should be `100 + number`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding the wrong variable. Use this instead:

```
System.out.println(" Your value + 100 is " + ( 100 + number));
```

Answer (score 2):

Text is the String, number an int, thus use:

```
System.out.println(" Your value + 100 is " + ( 100 + number));
```

For Strings + concatenates.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(text) + 100;

 System.out.println(" Your value + 100 is " + ( number));
```

or

```
System.out.println(" Your value + 100 is " + ( 100 + number));
```

For a string "+" works to concatenate , i.e append the string together :)